# Not able to implement "Recently Played" playlist in music player

Tags: android, audio-player, android-sharedpreferences, android-music-player

I'm trying to implement "Recently Played" playlist in my music player that shows those songs which were played by user recently(in a recyclerView). But what I code does is, it only stores the last  played song.

What I want: 
If I have 2 songs in my music player say, A and B. I played song A first. Then it should be added to recently played list(at first position). After that if I play song B, it also should be added to list(not replacing A)but pushing A down and B occupying first position. So the final list should look like : B on the top and A below it.

But what my app does:
ONly stores the last played and replaces anything else i.e after song A is played if I play song B, song A will be replaced by song B and there will only be one song in the list.

Finally my problem is as mentioned above, app only stores one song (the last played). BTW I'm using sharedpreference for this.

Code:

```
 public void storeAudioPlaylist(SongInfoModel songInfoModel) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    playlistStore.add(songInfoModel);
    String json = gson.toJson(playlistStore);
    editor.putString("audioPlayList", json);
    editor.apply();
}

 public ArrayList<SongInfoModel> loadAudioPlaylist() {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = preferences.getString("audioPlayList", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SongInfoModel>>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

The above 2 functions are used for storing song object to array and retrieving the  array respectively.

Code :

```
  public void onClickListener(SongInfoModel song, int position) {

storageUtil.storeAudioPlaylist(song); // this calls the method and passes 
                                         the song model(ID,name,artist..etc)


   }
```

Comment: You might want to read up on this concept of Least Recently Used: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html